# run rspec tests from specific folder using rake

Tags: rspec, rake, capybara

I wish to use rake to run specific tests in a folder contained withing spec folder. My folder structure is as follows:

```
- tests
  -spec
   - folder_A
   - folder_B
- rakefile
```

So for example when certain code is deployed I just wish to run the tests in folder_A. How do I do this using rake? My rakefile lives in my tests folder. I currently have the command:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
 task :default => :spec
```

This runs all tests in the spec folder as you would expect. I have tried moving the rake file into the spec folder and editing the rake task to this:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:folder_A)
 task :default => :folder_A
```

However this gives me the message: "No examples matching ./spec{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb could be found" (note that within folders A and B I have sub directories for the different areas of the application under test)

Is it possible for me to have 2 different rake tasks in the same rakefile that will run the tests just from folder_A?

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 10):

Why not just use rspec?

```
rspec spec/folder_A
```

---

**UPDATED RESPONSE**

The `:spec` in your `Rakefile` refers to the Rspec rake task, not the folder. You can send options to the task by passing a block as shown on the [rake-task doc page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task)

In your case you can pass in a glob for the folder using the `pattern` option.

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.pattern = 'spec/folder_A/*/_spec.rb'
end
```

For two different rake tasks you'll need to instantiate your `RakeTask` within each of your own tasks. So your entire `Rakefile` would look something like this:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :folder_A do
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'spec/folder_A/*/_spec.rb'
  end
  Rake::Task["spec"].execute
end

task :folder_B do
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'spec/folder_B/*/_spec.rb'
  end
  Rake::Task["spec"].execute
end

task :default do
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
  Rake::Task["spec"].execute
end
```

See [the RakeTask doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/RakeTask#pattern-instance_method) for details on the `pattern` method and other options.

Comment: Hi jwadsack - yeah I just use rspec currently, like you have suggested above. The main reason I wished to use a rake file was because I wished to re-run all failing tests using this gem(https://github.com/dblock/rspec-rerun) and this uses a rake file.

Comment: Hello jwadsack, your code snippet above got me onto invoking rspec directly using dependencies instead of trying hacky system calls to rspec from my rake; had no idea the integration was so tight out of the box. Thanks man you made my sprint!

Comment: Very helpful, years later. Allowed me to hook up rake tasks for executing different test suites (unit, integration, etc.) in different CI environments without verbose RSpec commands